# Program throws NullPointerException when i try to search in drives?

Tags: java, file, nullpointerexception, drive

I wrote a program to find file or directory.
Its working properly when i am trying to Search file with in  **Directory**
example
 `java FileSearch abc.txt f:\xyz`
But when i am try to search file from **local drive** than program throw Exception
`java FileSearch abc.txt f:\`
after **Showing** all the search result throws NullPointerException.

[image: nullpointerexcepion]

code is :

```
import java.io.*;
class FileSearch{
static String fd;
static boolean flg=true;
public static void main(String arr[]){
    fd=arr[0];
    String path=arr[1];
    String dir[]=new File(path).list();
    new FileSearch().finder(dir,path);
    if(flg){System.out.print("File not found.");}
}
public void finder(String[] dir,String path){
    for(int i=0;i<dir.length;i++){
        if(dir[i].equals(fd)){
            System.out.println(path+"\\"+fd);
            flg=false;
        }
        if(new File(path,dir[i]).isDirectory())
            finder(new File(path,dir[i]).list(),path+"\\"+dir[i]);
    }   
}
}
```

I want to know why this exception is thrown and how can i fix it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[list()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list%28%29)

> The documentation of `listFiles()` mentions that it will return `null`
>   if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O
>   error occurs.  Additionally, you would need to check with
>   `file.canRead()` whether the application can read the directory.

IMHO

Always use it this way;

```
String[] files = file.list();
if (files!=null) {
    for (String f : files) processFile(f);
}
```

Recommend this;

```
File directory = new File(directoryName);

//get all the files from a directory
File[] fList = directory.listFiles();

if(fList != null){
    for (File file : fList){
        if (file.isFile()){
            System.out.println(file.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Do let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I agree, listFiles() really returns null if folder content cannot be read. This can happen when traversing $Recycle.Bin for example.

Comment: Different platforms return different things for `list` and `listFiles`. I've found that Windows returns `null` for empty directories in certain scenarios, but Unix systems almost always return an empty array. Also, if you don't have access (like stated in the answer, `canRead` returns `false`), then some systems return `null`, some systems return an empty array. The platform consistency in the non-NIO libraries is basically non-existent. If you can use Java 7, you should use the other answer instead.

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative is to using the FileVisitor interface introduced in JDK7 to perform the search. The link at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html provides details on how to use the FileVisitor interface.

The following code block is a re implementation of the search that should be able to list files at a windows drive level in addition to normal directories. Note that the implementation uses Files.walkTree method that is provided as part of the NIO 2 File IO Operations.

```
public class FileSearch {
    static String fd;
    static boolean flg = true;

    static class FileSearchVisitor extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path> {

        private final Path pathToSearch;

        boolean found;

        FileSearchVisitor(Path pathToSearch) {
            found = false;
            this.pathToSearch = pathToSearch;
        }

        public boolean isFound() {
            return found;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
            super.preVisitDirectory(dir, attrs);
            if (pathToSearch.getFileName().equals(dir.getFileName())) {
                System.out.println("Found " + pathToSearch);
                found = true;
            }
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
            super.visitFile(file, attrs);
            if (pathToSearch.getFileName().equals(file.getFileName())) {
                System.out.println("Found " + pathToSearch);
                found = true;
            }
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) {
            System.err.println("Visit failed for file at path : " + file);
            exc.printStackTrace();
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String arr[]) throws Exception {
        fd = arr[0];
        String path = arr[1];

        final Path searchFile = Paths.get(fd);
        Path filePath = Paths.get(path);
        FileSearchVisitor visitor = new FileSearchVisitor(searchFile);
        Files.walkFileTree(filePath, visitor);
        if (!visitor.isFound()) {
            System.out.print("File not found.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you fix it:

```
import java.io.*;
class FileSearch{
static String fd;
static boolean flg=true;
public static void main(String arr[]){
    fd=arr[0];
    String path=arr[1];
    String dir[]=new File(path).list();
    new FileSearch().finder(dir,path);
    if(flg){System.out.print("File not found.");}
}
public void finder(String[] dir,String path){
    if(dir == null){
        return;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<dir.length;i++){
        if(dir[i].equals(fd)){
            System.out.println(path+"\\"+fd);
            flg=false;
        }
        if(new File(path,dir[i]).isDirectory())
            finder(new File(path,dir[i]).list(),path+"\\"+dir[i]);
    }   
}
}
```

Why? String dir[]=new File(path).list(); on the directory you specified is null
so when you call dir.length you will get null pointer exception

another thing that will help you understand, 
System.out.print(new File(path).isDirectory());
if its false, then you will get null pointer exception.