# How to read all mp3 files in my computer in java?

Tags: java, exception, file-io, nullpointerexception, mp3

My aim is to get list of all mp3 files in my computer(below code in c: directory). But when I run this code, I am getting `NullPointerException`. But works well for other directory like(e:).

```
public class music {

public static void main(String args[]){
    extract("c:\\");

}
public static void extract(String p){
    File f=new File(p);
    File l[]=f.listFiles();

    for(File x:l)
    {
        //System.out.println(x.getName());

        if(x.isHidden()||!x.canRead())
            continue;
        if(x.isDirectory())
            extract(x.getPath());
        else if(x.getName().endsWith(".mp3"))
            System.out.println(x.getPath()+"\\"+x.getName());

    }

}
}
```

Comment: May I interest you in `DirectoryStream<Path>` ?

Comment: And which line is the exception coming from?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listRoots()At least start with listRoots, not c:\\

Comment: Do you have any OS specific folders with permission previleges?

Comment: Could you also post your stacktrace in this question. Do see in javaDoc that listFiles can return null when: "...this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs."

Comment: it may sound stupid but did you try extract("C:"); ?

Comment: if you get any popup when clicking any directory - saying 'You don't currently have permission to this folder' or any access denied error. This will throw I/O error

Comment: Also, be wary that your test for ".mp3" will dismiss other case spellings like ".Mp3". MP3 files may also occasionally named with totally different extensions (although very uncommon).

Comment: Thank you all... i didn't check the list for null....thats the problem...Got output:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows operating system. C Drive (Windows drive) have system file that used by windows while running and some file that locked by windows. When your code try to access that files its through exception.
Try to run this code with other then C:// drive.. 
Add Try catch or null check for this files:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Music {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        extract("c:\\");
    }
    public static void extract(String p){
        File f=new File(p);
        File l[]=f.listFiles();
        for(File x:l){
            if(x==null) return;
            if(x.isHidden()||!x.canRead()) continue;
            if(x.isDirectory()) extract(x.getPath());
            else if(x.getName().endsWith(".mp3"))
                System.out.println(x.getPath()+"\\"+x.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Spartan I am asking since `for (Type x : nullReference) if(...)` will throw NPE before it will execute `if`.

Comment: @pshemo but in for loop. not check value of list element. just count

Comment: `l` is result of `f.listFiles()` so if it will return `null` instead of list of files placed in `f` loop `for(File x:l)` will throw NPE before entering its body.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by `and store in list[]`. Could you post full code of working solution so I could test it because I am not able to solve this problem with your answer.

Comment: Code you posted is the one from OP question. Please include your solution in it.

Comment: This code throws NPE for folders like `c:\Documents and Settings` (at least for Windows 7) so it doesn't solve OP problem.

Comment: no right now i m using windows 7 and this code work fine for me.

Comment: Even if something works for you it doesn't have to mean that it will work everywhere. I am one of examples. Anyway if you remove `if(x==null){return;}` will it change anything on your PC? Will you get NPE anywhere?

Comment: yes it throw NPE at last of when print all the file.
note... Exception throw at the end for program when program print all the mp3 file.

Comment: If something doesn't work then it means there is problem with it. Anyway I'll assume that OP has similar OS as you so if your approach solves his problem then it's fine and farther discussion is not necessary. To be fair probably best solution would be combining our two answers.

Comment: @Pshemo i think you are right.now Its 2 late i go to sleep(6 hr); i check this next day. good night. and sry for bad english :)

Comment: I just hope you really tested this code when you said that it throws NPE after printing all mp3 files and not just assumed that it will do it like in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18795000/1393766) question. Note that you accepted answer like mine but you posted different one.

Comment: @Pshemo yes the both case are same. And link of question you attach asked by myself. on that case i resolve this problem in same way.I accepted answer because well explained and its give me the idea what actually the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I got NPE with your code when it tried to access some [not real directories like `c:\Documents and Settings`](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/37546421-668f-4976-b128-1f50bf658e73/cant-access-documents-and-settings?forum=w7itprosecurity).

To solve this problem you can skip iterating over directories that returns `null` from `listFiles()` like in this code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    extract(new File("c:\\"));

}

public static void extract(File dir) {
    File l[] = dir.listFiles();

    if (l == null) {
        System.out.println("[skipped] " + dir);
        return;
    }

    for (File x : l) {
        if (x.isDirectory())
            extract(x);
        if (x.isHidden() || !x.canRead()) 
            continue;
        else if (x.getName().endsWith(".mp3"))
            System.out.println(x.getPath());//name should be included in path
    }

}
```